# Locally a product equals fiber bundle?

Tags: general-topology, fiber-bundles

I know the definition of a fiber bundle as a map $p:E \rightarrow B$ such that the preimage of any open set in $B$ is diffeomorphic to a product and fits in a commutative diagram with the projection $p$.

If we have a manifold $E$ and we know that it is locally a product, i.e. for every point $p \in E$ there exist an open set $V$ containing $p$ such that $V \simeq U \times F$ where $F$ is some fixed manifold and $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for a fixed $n$. Is that enough to see that $E$ is a fiber bundle in the above sense? In that case, how do we construct $B$? If  not, could anyone provide a counterexample?

Also it is considered a good answer if someone provides a good reference where this is explained.

Comment: According to your second "definition" every $n-$manifold would be a fiber bundle. Every point has a neighbourhood which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be seen as a product, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^{n}\simeq\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times\mathbb{R}$. This does not imply that an $n-$manifold is a fibre bundle with fiber $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Dario -- Every manifold is a fiber bundle: $M\cong M\times\{0\}$.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow: Indeed, but according to that definition any $n-$manifold could be seen as a fiber bundle with fiber $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ with any $d\leq n$, in particular as I pointed out in the other comment as a fiber bundle with fiber $\mathbb{R}$.